# how to stop http-server on a specific port?

Tags: shell, operating-system, erlang, localhost, httpserver

I am using http-server in order to load http://localhost:8484 on a specific folder. (For testing purposes)
the os commands I run in my code are:

```
http-server -p 8484 test/
```

and after I finish downloading whatever I run:

```
http-server stop
```

However, after the test is done, I see that the http-server with port 8484 is still alive!

by running `ps aux | grep http`

What command should I run in order to stop it?

- I am using Mac OSX (El Capitan version)
- I write the code in erlang (though I don't think it matters since I am running shell commands from the code).
- http-server: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

My code in erlang:

```
my_test_() ->
  Pid = spawn(fun() ->
          Info = os:cmd("http-server -p 8484 test/resources"),
          io:format(user,"*** Server: ~p~n",[Info])
        end),

%%% Do some job %%%

  Pid2 = spawn(fun() ->
           Info = os:cmd("http-server stop"),
           timer:sleep(200),
           io:format(user,"*** Server stop: ~p~n",[Info])
         end),
  timer:sleep(200),
  exit(Pid2, kill),
  exit(Pid, kill).
```

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
kill -9 {pid}
```

Also, out of interest, if you want to see all processes running on a specific port, use:

```
lsof -i :{port}
```

**EDIT:** Using *kill -9...* is a bit harsh, I know, there is probably a more graceful way of doing it, but it does get the job done ;-)

Comment: thanks for the answer. That doesn't help using erlang. I am editing my question to make it clear

Answer (score 1):

For **Windows** users use the command prompt (**cmd**):

**Method 1:**
Just do <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> on the same console where the **http-server** is running

**Method 2:** Find and Kill the process:

i. **Find** the ***process-id*** which uses the particular ***port number*** (say 8484)

```
    netstat  -ano  |  findstr  8484
```

*Result*: TCP    0.0.0.0:**8484**           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       **21816**

ii. **Kill** the process using the found **process-id** (say 21816)

```
    taskkill /F /PID 21816
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [perc](https://github.com/msantos/perc) - since Node.js http-server is not Erlang process, but Unix process, you need to use the module (or dig it's code to see the implementation ;) ) .

Alternatively, from Erlang `os:cmd("kill -9 5607").` (where 5607 is your unix pid);